# How to disable the element at position 0 in spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have three element in spinner.I want to not select the item which is at position 0.How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {           
    if (i!=0) {
        //do your work here
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
spinner.setSelection(position, false);
```

Probably that solve your problem. :)